# Trustable communication between your server and the browser?

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, web-applications

I’ve always been having this problem in mind and always went with the easier more solution of doing it on the server. However, I decided I can ask more people about it, may be one of the enlightened can help me with a reliable solution.

Problem: you’re developing a web application that servers many users. Part of the features you offer involves calling an external API. That call is done for each user. The call can be made by either your server or the browser’s JavaScript. In either cases you persist the result of processing the data from the API call in the server’s database. I would like to offload calling the API and processing the results to the browser’s JavaScript and after it finishes it will callback the server with the data to persist. The problem that I see with this approach is that anyone can modify that JavaScript’s behavior (how easy is that thnx to firebug and its likes) to persist malicious/incorrect data on the server.

How can I - the server - trust that the data coming to me from JavaScript - following the previous scenario - is correct and not altered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create some data on server A, give it to a client, and have that client pass it to server B verbatim, then you simply need to include an anti-tamper hash with it. Server A and B share a secret which they use as salt. As the client doesn't know this salt, it is unable to fabricate authentic data for itself.

Note that on its own, this technique only gives a strong degree of confidence that server A originated the data. There are other vulnerabilities you may need to consider, such as replay attacks of old data etc.

Comment: If I understand it right, Server A and Server B will always have to include the anti-tamper hash with javascript only being a middle man who forwards messages?... the thing is, it's all abt how you create the anti-tamper hash... because I was assuming that javascript will get some results of an API call... process it, and then forward the results... ur solution is perfect if no javascript processing is involved in the middle... javascript just acts as a forwarder... I like that solution

Comment: That's correct. If you have the client side transforming the data, then you have to operate under the assumption that the data is tainted and possibly malicious. Pretty much what Nick Craver asserts in the other answer.

Answer (score 5):

The simple answer is **you can't**, JavaScript is the least secure mechanism in the pipeline - the easiest to manipulate.  If you want it to be secure, you should *never* rely on JavaScript for it.

Think of it in a more general sense: you can only secure an environment you at least somewhat control...you have *no* control over the browser, the JavaScript engine, or the user manipulating it.

Always validate server-side, always, always, always.

Comment: I'm sure you ment "never rely on JavaScript"!?

Comment: @aefxx - I meant "do something secure"...clarified :)

Comment: aefxx was pointing out your typo: "If you want it to be secure, you should *ever* rely on JavaScript for it."